# Why $\sum_{i=1}^n e_i $ is a good estimator of the measurement error variance?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

Why the sum of the $n$ squared residuals from
a simple linear regression divided by $n - 2$ might be expected to estimate the
measurement error variance?

Comment: Please, avoid `\limits`, `\displaystyle` etc. in titles because it takes more vertical space.